# Tranpose multiple columns by key/value and combine them

Tags: r

I have the following dataframe:

```
date <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
value1 <-c(10,20,30,0,0,0,0)
key1 <- c(100,200,300,0,0,0,0)
value2 <- c(0,0,0,0,40,30,20)
key2 <- c(0,0,0,0,400,500,600)
df <- data.frame(date,value1,key1,value2,key2)
```

It looks like this:

```
date value1 key1 value2 key2
1    10     100  0      0
2    20     200  0      0
3    30     300  0      0
4    0      0    0      0   
5    0      0    40     400   
6    0      0    30     500    
7    0      0    20     600
```

I want to transform it like this:

```
date 100    200  300  400  500  600
1    10     0    0    0    0    0
2    0      20   0    0    0    0
3    10     0    30   0    0    0
4    10     0    0    0    0    0   
5    10     0    0    40   0    0   
6    10     0    0    0    30   0    
7    10     0    0    0    0    20
```

I can tranpose them manually like this:

```
library(tidyr)
numbers_transpose <- df %>% spread(key = key1, value = value1)
numbers_transpose <- numbers_transpose %>% spread(key = key2, value = value2)
```

But I have like 50 pairs and would like to automate it. How to do it the easy way?

Comment: Oh that is a mistake. Sorry. I edit it

Comment: Also, for the second column, why the values 10 is repeated, as the initial have only date1 with 10

Comment: Ok your code seems to work fine on the toy example. In the real dataset I have N/A values instead of zeros and it does not work correctly. Should I modify the filter(key != 0) statement?

Comment: if it is real `NA` instead of `N/A`, it is much easier, that is, use `values_drop_na = TRUE` in `pivot_longer` and remove the `filter` step.  If it is character "N/A" either convert to `NA` or use `filter(key != "N/A")`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have a little problem with the column names. In the real data they are llike X100 and D_,100. I tried to use names_to = c('.X', 'grp') and names_from = c('.D_.', 'grp'), but no success. Where is my mistake in the transformation?

Comment: You don't need to change the `names_to`, it is for the grouping column and the value column, iif your column names are `X100`, `Y100`, `D100`, this should work.  But, if there is a name like `X_100`, have to make adjustment in `names_sep` i.e `names_sep= "(?<=[^0-9])(?=[0-9])"`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209728/discussion-between-pyseeker-and-akrun).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could convert to 'long' format with `pivot_longer` and then reshape it back

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = -date, names_to = c('.value', 'grp'), 
             names_sep= "(?<=[a-z])(?=[0-9])", values_drop_na = TRUE) %>%
    filter(key != 0) %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = key, values_from = value,
           values_fill = list(value = 0)) %>%
    select(-grp)
# A tibble: 6 x 7
#   date `100` `200` `300` `400` `500` `600`
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1    10     0     0     0     0     0
#2     2     0    20     0     0     0     0
#3     3     0     0    30     0     0     0
#4     5     0     0     0    40     0     0
#5     6     0     0     0     0    30     0
#6     7     0     0     0     0     0    20
```